# Show available wifi in UITableView similar to iHome Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, sdk

I'd like to show a list of available wifi in my next app, similar to iHome Connect. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ihome-connect-setup-app-for/id450241802?mt=8

I've done some googling and have found out that the only way to do this is to use a private API (illegal), but there are apps in the app store that are doing this?

Has anyone had the need to do this? If so, what private API did you use and was your app rejected?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using private API and your app will likely be rejected.

Stumbler helper library: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/